# Add a VPC node to ELB programmatically

Tags: ruby, rubygems, amazon-web-services

The following code is intended to add a newly deployed EC2 instance in a VPC to a load balancer. (This is pretty obviously test/dummy code, but the general workflow is the same in a real system)

```
require 'yaml'
gem 'aws-sdk','1.6.0'
require 'aws-sdk'

AWS.config({
  :access_key_id => KEY,
  :secret_access_key => SECRET_KEY
})
ec2 = AWS::EC2.new
elb = AWS::ELB.new

i = ec2.instances["i-abcd1234"]
elb.load_balancers["lb-name"].instances.register(i)
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
AWS::ELB::Errors::ValidationError: ELB in VPC is not supported in this version of API. Please try 2011-11-15 or newer.
```

My aws-sdk gem is the most current version available through RubyGems, it was updated this week. Is this just not a feature available in the Ruby SDK for AWS? What can I do to add a VPC node to a Load Balancer with Ruby code, through this gem or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved: This error was the result of the ELB portion of the aws-sdk gem using an old version of the AWS API. A new gem version (1.6.1) was released on August 6, 2012 which causes ELB to use the 2012-06-01 version of the API, and now instances can be added to an ELB using code like in the question.