# Are there any good chef/ruby aws-sdk examples for ELB manipulation

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, amazon-elb, aws-sdk

I'm writing a chef cookbook and I need to attach and detach instances to an existing ELB.  I've looked over the "aws" cookbook but it uses right_aws gem and all of our other LWRPs are written against aws-sdk.  I can find plenty of examples of the aws-sdk gem for EC2 and S3 usage, but I can't find any existing recipes for ELB.

Does anyone know of any, or can you offer some guidance on using ELBs in a VPC via Chef?

Answer (score 0):

After downloading and going through the aws-sdk-ruby [source](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/), brushing up on ruby itself, and finding [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800472/add-a-vpc-node-to-elb-programmatically), I was able to construct the following as ruby classes in the coobkook's library folder:

elb.rb:

```
class Chef
    class Resource
        class AmazonElb < Chef::Resource::Amazon
            def initialize(name, run_context=nil)
                super(name, run_context)
                @resource_name      = :amazon_elb
                @provider           = Chef::Provider::AmazonElb
                @action             = :attach
                @allowed_actions    = [:attach, :detach]
            end
        end

        def instance_id (arg=nil)
            set_or_return(
                :instance_id,
                arg,
                :kind_of            => [String, NilClass]
            )
        end

        def elb_name (arg=nil)
            set_or_return(
                :elb_name,
                arg,
                :kind_of            => [String, NilClass]
            )
        end
    end
end
```

elb_provider.rb:

```
class Chef
    class Provider
        class AmazonElb < Chef::Provider::Amazon
            def initialize(new_resource, run_context)
                #super(new_resource, runcontext)
                super
                @ec2 = AWS::EC2.new
                @elb = AWS::ELB.new
            end

            def load_current_resource
                @current_resource = @new_resource
                @current_resource
            end

            def define_resource_requirements
                requirements.assert(:attach, :detach) do |a|
                    a.assertion {
                        @new_resource.instance_id != nil &&
                        @new_resource.elb_name != nil
                    }
                    a.failure_message(Chef::Exceptions::ELBException, "The attributes instance_id and elb_name must be specified.")
                end
            end

            def action_attach
                new_resource = @new_resource
                instance = @ec2.instances[new_resource.instance_id]
                @elb.load_balancers["#{new_resource.elb_name}"].instances.register(instance)
            end

            def action_detach
                new_resource = @new_resource
                instance = @ec2.instances[new_resource.instance_id]
                @elb.load_balancers["#{new_resource.elb_name}"].instances.deregister(instance)
            end

        end
    end
end
```

I can now call this as:

```
amazon_elb "something" do
    instance_id "i-xxx"
    elb_name "name of elb"
    aws_access_key xxx
    aws_secret_key xxx
end
```

Note: this relies on another set of classes that created as well in order to expose the aws-sdk to the cookbook, retrieve the access keys, and relies on the aws-sdk gem being installed.  The above won't work as is but should give a good starting point.